# When I originally installed ubuntu and was prompted to set username and password my computer crashed. How do I set my username and password

Tags: password

Just as the title says.
I just installed Ubuntu, and my computer wasn't working rite, so I quit Ubuntu when it was asking me to set my password and username.
Now when I do the whoami command it returns root.
I'm going through my course that is having me practice this stuff such as /home/username and I get this message in return:
-bash: /home/username: No such file or directory

Comment: I suggest you reinstall.

Comment: can I not just adduser?

Comment: You have a corrupted part installed system. Reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the normal installer with normal options, then you aborted the install before completion.

Ubuntu is not designed to compensate for faulty hardware.

Ensure you have properly functioning hardware, then re-run the installer.